# Android - Custom view text color Selector

Tags: android, android-view

I created a custom view which contains a `TextView` inside and at some point I will need to change the text colour.

Using a standard `declare-styleable` with `<attr name="android:textColor"/>` works.

```
  <declare-styleable name="CustomStatusButton">
    <attr name="android:text"/>
    <attr name="android:textColor"/>
    <attr name="android:enabled"/>
  </declare-styleable>
```

I use this to set the colour:

```
  val textColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable. CustomStatusButton_android_textColor, Color.BLACK)
  tv_button_text.setTextColor(textColor)
```

--

Now I need to set a Selector colour for enabled/disabled states. so I created this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/red" android:state_enabled="true" />
  <item android:color="@color/green" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

and

```
  <CustomStatusButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="SAVE"
      android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color_selector"
      />
```

But this doesn't set the colour depending on enable/disable. it only tastes the first colour which is red.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in this code

`val textColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.CustomStatusButton_android_textColor, Color.BLACK)`

You try to get color but you need to get `ColorStateList`

Comment: Yes, @Mkhytar is right. resource.getColor(R.color.you_define) is also failed. only getColorStateList(R.color.you_define) is available.